# Exclude child jQuery object when detecting window resize for the parent object

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

Using `$(window).resize(functionA)`, how do I re-run objectA without re-running objectB on resize?

objectB requires objectA to work, because objectB uses `$(this)`.

Here is the jQuery:

```
var objectA = $('.row').find('.noLimitBackgroundPNGAcontainer').resize().each(function() {

  // Get on screen image
  var screenImage = $(this).find('.imgWrapper>img');

  // Create new offscreen image to test
  var theImage = new Image();
  theImage.src = screenImage.attr("src");

  // Get accurate measurements from that.
  var imageWidth = theImage.width;
  var imageHeight = theImage.height;



  //Finds tallest height out of all columns inside every row containing any image.
  var objectB = $(this).find('.imgWrapper>img').each(function() {

    var maxHeight = 0;

    $(this).closest('.row').find('.evaluateHeight').each(function checkHeight() {
      if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
      };
    });
  });


  //these variables find the correct img width and img height for imitating object-fit CSS.
  var actualIMGwidthWhenConstrainedByColumnHeight = maxHeight * (imageWidth / imageHeight);

  var imgContainerWidth = $(this).closest(".noLimitBackgroundPNGAcontainer").width();

  var actualIMGheightWhenConstrainedByColumnWidth = ($(imgContainerWidth)) * (($(imageHeight)) / ($(imageWidth)));




  //This code imitates the object-fit CSS feature.
  if (imgContainerWidth > actualIMGwidthWhenConstrainedByColumnHeight) {

    $(this).closest(".backgroundPNGAfix").width(actualIMGwidthWhenConstrainedByColumnHeight);
    $(this).height(maxHeight);

  } else {

    $(this).closest(".backgroundPNGAfix").width('100%');
    $(this).height(actualIMGheightWhenConstrainedByColumnWidth);

  };

});
$(window).resize(objectA).not(objectB);
```

Comment: Neither `functionA` nor `functionB` are actually functions. They're jQuery objects.

Comment: Pointy, thank you for this. I'll edit my question accordingly.